# Extract dict value from list of dict?

Tags: python

I have this parameter

```
x = [{'id': 1L}, {'id': 4L}]
```

My list contains dicts that **contain long integers**, so there is a need to convert them to integers.

I want to save only values of id in a new list like

```
y = [1, 4]
```

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
ids = [y['id'] for y in x]
```

This assumes that every dictionary has a key 'id'. If you're not sure that key exists in every dictionary, you can use this one:

```
ids = [y['id'] for y in x if 'id' in y]
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want:

```
[a["id"] for a in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itemgetter` from `operator`:

```
y = list(map(itemgetter('id'), x))
```